# In retrieving methods from a class how do I create a generic list if the parameter type is a list and fill the list from a datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a Windows Form application to test methods of classes created for another application. The panel is filled with controls for each parameter, including a DataGridView for parameters of List type. When I click the test-button, the parameter values will be read from the controls and the selected method of the class will be invoked. This works for strings and integers, but I'm having trouble instantiating the parameter type in case it is a List and filling it from a DataGridView.

Here is the current code (C#):

```
private void btnTestMethod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (_selectedClass != null && _selectedMethod != string.Empty)
        {
            ConstructorInfo classConstructor = _selectedClass.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            object classObject = classConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { });

            List<object> parameterValues = new List<object>();
            List<Type> parameterTypes = new List<Type>();

            for (int idx = 0; idx < pnlParameters.Controls.Count; idx++)
            {
                string parameterName = pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Name;
                var parameter = _selecedParameters.First(param => param.Name.Equals(parameterName));

                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    object parameterObject;

                    parameterTypes.Add(parameter.ParameterType);

                    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(parameter.ParameterType))
                    {
                        case TypeCode.String:
                            parameterObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(string), new object[] { pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Text.ToCharArray() });
                            break;

                        case TypeCode.Int32:
                            parameterObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Int32), new object[] { Convert.ToInt32(pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Text) });
                            break;

                        case TypeCode.Int64:
                            parameterObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Int32), new object[] { Convert.ToInt64(pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Text) });
                            break;

                        case TypeCode.Object:
                            //first check if list<T>
                            //then create an empty list<T>
                            //then check if datagridview
                            //Read each row into list

                            if (parameter.ParameterType.IsGenericType &&
                                parameter.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
                            {
                                // resolve T in List<T>
                                Type type = parameter.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                                // avoid problems with List<Nullable<Something>>
                                type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;

                                // create list
                                //IList objList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                                IList objList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(parameter.ParameterType);

                                if (pnlParameters.Controls[idx].GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
                                {
                                    using (DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)pnlParameters.Controls[idx])
                                    {
                                        List<string> properties = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsPublic).Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

                                        foreach (DataRow row in dgv.Rows)
                                        {
                                            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(parameter.ParameterType);
                                            foreach (string colName in properties)
                                            {

                                            }
                                            objList.Add(obj);
                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            parameterObject = Activator.CreateInstance(parameter.ParameterType);
                            break;

                        default:
                            parameterObject = Activator.CreateInstance(parameter.ParameterType);
                            break;
                    }
                    parameterValues.Add(parameterObject);
                }
            }

            //Now invoke the method and retrieve the result
            MethodInfo classMethod = _selectedClass.GetMethod(_selectedMethod, parameterTypes.ToArray());
            object testResult = classMethod.Invoke(classObject, parameterValues.ToArray());

            //Show result in treeview
            PopulateResults(testResult);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowErrorMessage(ex);
    }

    ResetParameters();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was a bit impatient (and lazy) and asked ChatGPT (AI). Together we came up with the following solution:

```
private void btnTestMethod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvokeMethod();
}

private void InvokeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        if (_selectedClass != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedMethod))
        {
            ConstructorInfo classConstructor = _selectedClass.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            object classObject = classConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { });

            List<object> parameterValues = new List<object>();
            List<Type> parameterTypes = new List<Type>();

            for (int idx = 0; idx < pnlParameters.Controls.Count; idx++)
            {
                string parameterName = pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Name;
                var parameter = _selectedParameters.FirstOrDefault(param => param.Name.Equals(parameterName));

                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    object parameterObject;

                    parameterTypes.Add(parameter.ParameterType);

                    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(parameter.ParameterType))
                    {
                        case TypeCode.String:
                            parameterObject = pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Text;
                            break;

                        case TypeCode.Int16:
                            if (short.TryParse(pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Text, out short shortValue))
                                parameterObject = shortValue;
                            else
                                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Int16 value for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                            break;

                        case TypeCode.Int32:
                            if (int.TryParse(pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Text, out int intValue))
                                parameterObject = intValue;
                            else
                                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Int32 value for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                            break;

                        case TypeCode.Int64:
                            if (long.TryParse(pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Text, out long longValue))
                                parameterObject = longValue;
                            else
                                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Int64 value for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                            break;

                        case TypeCode.Boolean:
                            switch (pnlParameters.Controls[idx])
                            {
                                case CheckBox checkBox:
                                    parameterObject = checkBox.Checked;
                                    break;

                                case TextBox textBox:
                                default:
                                    if (bool.TryParse(pnlParameters.Controls[idx].Text, out bool boolValue))
                                        parameterObject = boolValue;
                                    else
                                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Boolean value for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;

                        case TypeCode.Object:
                            if (parameter.ParameterType.IsGenericType &&
                                parameter.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
                            {
                                Type elementType = parameter.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                                if (pnlParameters.Controls[idx] is DataGridView dataGridView)
                                {
                                    IList listObject = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(parameter.ParameterType);

                                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
                                    {
                                        if (!row.IsNewRow)
                                        {
                                            object elementObject = Activator.CreateInstance(elementType);

                                            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                                            {
                                                string columnName = cell.OwningColumn.Name;
                                                PropertyInfo property = elementType.GetProperty(columnName);

                                                if (property != null)
                                                {
                                                    object cellValue = cell.Value;

                                                    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(property.PropertyType))
                                                    {
                                                        case TypeCode.String:
                                                            property.SetValue(elementObject, cellValue);
                                                            break;

                                                        case TypeCode.Int16:
                                                            if (short.TryParse(cellValue.ToString(), out short shortCellValue))
                                                                property.SetValue(elementObject, shortCellValue);
                                                            else
                                                                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Int16 value for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                                                            break;
                                                        case TypeCode.Int32:
                                                            if (int.TryParse(cellValue.ToString(), out int intCellValue))
                                                                property.SetValue(elementObject, intCellValue);
                                                            else
                                                                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Int32 value for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                                                            break;
                                                        case TypeCode.Int64:
                                                            if (long.TryParse(cellValue.ToString(), out long lngCellValue))
                                                                property.SetValue(elementObject, lngCellValue);
                                                            else
                                                                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Int64 value for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                                                            break;
                                                        case TypeCode.Boolean:
                                                            if (bool.TryParse(cellValue.ToString(), out bool blnCellValue))
                                                                property.SetValue(elementObject, blnCellValue);
                                                            else
                                                                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Boolean value for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                                                            break;
                                                        case TypeCode.Object:
                                                            if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                                                            {
                                                                if (cellValue != null)
                                                                {
                                                                    object enumValue = Enum.Parse(property.PropertyType, cellValue.ToString());
                                                                    property.SetValue(elementObject, enumValue);
                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Enum value for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                property.SetValue(elementObject, cellValue);
                                                            }
                                                            break;
                                                        default:
                                                            property.SetValue(elementObject, cellValue);
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                            listObject.Add(elementObject);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    parameterObject = listObject;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid control type for List parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type for parameter: " + parameter.Name);
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported parameter type: " + parameter.ParameterType.Name);
                    }

                    parameterValues.Add(parameterObject);
                }
            }

            MethodInfo classMethod = _selectedClass.GetMethod(_selectedMethod, parameterTypes.ToArray());
            object result = classMethod.Invoke(classObject, parameterValues.ToArray());

            DisplayResults(result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowErrorMessage(ex);
    }
    //ResetParameters();
}

private void DisplayResults(object result)
{
    // Clear previous results
    pnlResults.Controls.Clear();
    Type resultType = result.GetType();

    switch (result)
    {
        case null:
            // No results to display
            Label lblNoResults = new Label();
            lblNoResults.Text = "No results available.";
            lblNoResults.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnlResults.Controls.Add(lblNoResults);
            break;

        case string strResult:
            // Single string result
            TextBox txtResult = new TextBox();
            txtResult.Text = strResult;
            txtResult.ReadOnly = true;
            txtResult.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnlResults.Controls.Add(txtResult);
            break;

        case ICollection collectionResult:
            // Collection of items
            if (resultType.IsGenericType)
            {
                TreeView tvCollection = XmlDocumentToTreeView(result);
                tvCollection.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                pnlResults.Controls.Add(tvCollection);
            }
            else
            {
                ListBox lstResult = new ListBox();
                lstResult.Items.AddRange(collectionResult.Cast<object>().ToArray());
                lstResult.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                pnlResults.Controls.Add(lstResult);
            }
            break;

        case DataTable dataTableResult:
            // Tabular data
            DataGridView dgvResult = new DataGridView();
            dgvResult.DataSource = dataTableResult;
            dgvResult.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnlResults.Controls.Add(dgvResult);
            break;

        case TreeNode treeNodeResult:
            // Hierarchical data
            TreeView tvResult = new TreeView();
            tvResult.Nodes.Add(treeNodeResult);
            tvResult.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnlResults.Controls.Add(tvResult);
            break;

        default:
            // Other types of results including custom objects
            Control resultControl = CreateObjectControl(result);
            if (resultControl != null)
            {
                resultControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                pnlResults.Controls.Add(resultControl);
            }
            else
            {
                // Unsupported result type
                Label lblUnsupported = new Label();
                lblUnsupported.Text = "Result type not supported for display.";
                lblUnsupported.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                pnlResults.Controls.Add(lblUnsupported);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private Control CreateObjectControl(object result)
{
    Type resultType = result.GetType();

    // Check if the result is a custom class with properties
    if (resultType.IsClass && !resultType.IsPrimitive && !resultType.IsArray)
    {
        // Create a panel to hold the property controls
        Panel resultPanel = new Panel();
        resultPanel.AutoScroll = true;

        // Get all public instance properties of the result object
        PropertyInfo[] properties = resultType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        int yOffset = 0;
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            Label lblPropertyName = new Label();
            lblPropertyName.Text = property.Name;
            lblPropertyName.Location = new Point(0, yOffset);
            resultPanel.Controls.Add(lblPropertyName);

            TextBox txtPropertyValue = new TextBox();
            object propertyValue = property.GetValue(result);
            txtPropertyValue.Text = propertyValue?.ToString() ?? "null";
            txtPropertyValue.Location = new Point(100, yOffset);
            txtPropertyValue.ReadOnly = true;
            resultPanel.Controls.Add(txtPropertyValue);

            yOffset += 30; // Adjust the vertical spacing as needed
        }

        return resultPanel;
    }

    return XmlDocumentToTreeView(result); // Serialize custom objects to XML
}

private TreeView XmlDocumentToTreeView(object result)
{
    TreeView tvResult = new TreeView();
    tvResult.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(SerializeToXml(result));

    TreeNode rootNode = CreateTreeNode(xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
    tvResult.Nodes.Add(rootNode);

    return tvResult;
}

public string SerializeToXml(object obj)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}

private TreeNode CreateTreeNode(XmlNode xmlNode)
{
    TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(xmlNode.Name);

    foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (childNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            TreeNode childTreeNode = CreateTreeNode(childNode);
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(childTreeNode);
        }
        else if (childNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(childNode.InnerText);
        }
    }

    return treeNode;
}
```